# If a power series has positive radius of convergence and is non-constant within radius of convergence , then is all the zeroes of the series isolated?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, power-series

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be a real power series with positive radius of convergence $R$

(including $R=+\infty$) , then we know that $f$ is continuous in $(-R,R)$ , so the zero set of $f$ i.e.

$Z(f):=\{x\in(-R,R):f(x)=0\}$ is closed . My question is ; is it true that if $f$ is non-constant in

$(-R,R)$ , then $Z(f)$ has no cluster point i.e. all the points of $Z(f)$ are isolated ?

Answer (score 2):

This is true (at least if you mean $Z(f)$ has no cluster point in $(-R,R)$; zeroes might accumulate at $\pm R$) and is a standard theorem in complex analysis.  Here is a sketch of a proof using only real methods.  Suppose $a\in (-R,R)$ is a cluster point of $Z(f)$.  It can be shown that $f(x)$ also has a power series expansion centered at $a$ which converges in a neighborhood of $a$ (basically, solve for a formal power series $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x-a)$, and then check that $g$'s coefficients don't grow too fast).  Now note that $a$ is also a cluster point of $Z(f')$, since otherwise $f$ would be strictly monotonic on each side of $a$ so $a$ would be an isolated zero.  By induction, we then see that $a$ is a cluster point of $Z(f^{(n)})$ for all the higher derivatives of $f$.  In particular, this means $f^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n$.  But these derivatives are (up to factors of $n!$) the coefficients of the power series expansion of $f$ near $a$.  So we conclude that actually, $f$ is identically zero in a neighborhood of $a$.

We have now shown that the set of cluster points of $Z(f)$ is an open set.  It is also a closed set, so by connectedness, if it is nonempty, then it is all of $(-R,R)$.  That is, if $Z(f)$ has a cluster point, then $f$ is identically $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. Actually, this follows from a stronger result; from Knopp's Theory of functions Part 1, chapter 7, Theorem 2:

> If both power series $$\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n\quad \text{and}\quad \sum
>  b_n(z-z_0)^n$$ have a positive radius of convergence, and if their
>   sums coincide for all points of a neighborhood of $z_0$, *or only for
>   an infinite number of such points* (distinct from one another and from
>   $z_0$) with the limit point $z_0$, then they are identical.

(emphasis mine.)

The proof goes like this: First, for $z=z_0$ it follows that $a_0=b_0$. Assume the first $m$ coefficients have been proven to be respectively equal. Then we have $$a_{m+1}+a_{m+2}(z-z_0)+\dots=b_{m+1}+b_{m+2}(z-z_0)+\dots$$ for all those infinitely many points. Let $z\to z_0$ along those points. Then, by continuity of the functions defined by the power series, $a_{m+1}=b_{m+1}$. Hence, both expansions are identical.

In your case, the second power series is just the null series, and this would mean $a_k=0$ for all $k$.

This result is referred to as the identity theorem for power series, and is used to prove the [identity theorem for analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) in complex analysis. This means roughly that if two complex differentiable functions are locally equal, then they are equal everywhere(!).